# How to obtain the output of a timer callback function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a function with the following input/output:

```
[out1,out2]=func(in1,in2);
```

and I want to call the function at a particular time using `timer` callback.

I understand the syntax to call `func` is

```
t=timer;
t.TimerFcn=@(~,~)func(in1,in2);
```

But how I do get the outputs of `func`?

Comment: I don’t think this can be done. There is no one fixed piece of code that is running when the callback is executed, so where would the output variables be declared? What other function should have access to these return values? Instead, try to find a different way of saving the results — a file, a global variable, an object property, etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation page for [Timer Callback Functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/timer-callback-functions.html) the example callback functions:

```
function myfile(obj, event)
function myfile
function myfile(obj, event, arg1, arg2)
```

Further reading of the page suggests that in general the proper function declaration looks something like:

```
function my_callback_fcn(obj, event, ...)
```

This, to me, is wrong evidence that there is no way to get a return value from the callback function.

I would suggest using the callback function to set an object property or a "global" variable with the desired return value(s).